# Handling an error condition in the compare function of std::qsort

Tags: c++, sorting, exception, stl, qsort

I am trying to figure out a way for `qsort` to throw an exception or indicate an error condition if the compare function finds that the elements are, for some reason, invalid for sorting.

For example, in this compare function, I need to indicate an error condition that my sorting is invalid if the return value of `some_function` is **`5`**.

How should I modify my compare function?

```
int compare (const void * a, const void * b)
{
  int ret1 = some_func(a);
  int ret2 = some_func(b):
  return ( ret1 - ret2 );
}
```

I am dealing with a legacy code base so I'm not in the position to use `std::sort` and due to the nature of the implementation calling `some_func` before hand might also involve huge amount of changes so I'm looking to understand if a workaround is possible.

Comment: Why not check it up front and avoid partially sorting your data structure?

Comment: qsort is a C library function that knows nothing about C++ and exceptions. Why are you not using `std::sort`, instead, and throw exceptions as often as you want?

Comment: BTW. [`std::sort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) is obliged to use a better algorithm than quicksort since C++11 (better in terms of big O notation).

Comment: @Yksisarvinen `qsort()` does not have to use quicksort

Comment: @Yksisarvinen N.B. notation is just that: notation. What you're really referring to is worst-case algorithmic complexity (in either time or memory).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++ allows you to throw whatever you need, not only exceptions but also other types, you could do something like throw an `int` if it suits your purposes and catch where you call the function with a `try-catch` block.

For what you need I think you can use STL exception library:

[Demostrative example](https://wandbox.org/permlink/b2wEJPohmsfstKrS):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <exception>

int count = 0;

int compare(const void *a, const void *b)
{  
    int ret1 = *(int*)a > *(int*)b;
    
    if (++count == 5) //throws exception when count reaches 5
        throw std::invalid_argument("Argument is not sortable");
    //you could throw count by simply using throw count

    return ret1;
}

int main()
{
    int x[]{2,1,3,5,6,1,7,2,5,3};
    try
    {
        //will sort until exception is thrown
        qsort(x, sizeof x / sizeof *x, sizeof(int), compare);
    }
    catch (const std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cout << e.what() << std::endl; //print exception in the console
        //handle the exception here
        //if you were to throw count you could cach it with
        //catch (int &e)
    }

    //note that the values were sorted until the exception was thrown
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof x / sizeof *x; i++){
        std::cout << x[i] << " ";
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Argument is not sortable
1 2 3 5 6 1 7 2 5 3  
        ^
     sorting 
     stopped 
      here
```

Comment: A bit odd to unconditionally instantiate an `std::exception` then throw it by copy like that. Why not a nice `throw std::runtime_error("explanation")`?

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings well I can't throw it by reference, it's standard issue throw by value, catch by reference, but you're right, your solution would be nicer, `throw std::invalid_argument("explanation");` would be more fitting though.

Answer (score 2):

Throwing an exception is potentially expensive, so you probably want to return an error condition. However, doing either approach inside the `compare` function is needlessly expensive in this case, since you would be doing the check multiple times for every element. Instead, you could just check for the error condition *before* calling `qsort` which is much more efficient:

```
auto ok = std::none_of(/* range */, /* predicate */);

if (ok)
  std::qsort(/* ... */)
else
  // report error
```